# how i can get back a Vertex Array from a Vertex Buffer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a way to get back an array of vertices from a vertex buffer?
I've tried to read the vertex buffer but it gives me back just a buffer . I've also tried to read the buffer array but it  gives me back an error of access . So, is there a way to read the Vertex Buffer?